# Determine the value of r where the series converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

show that $$ \big(r\big)^{ln(n)} =  \big(n\big)^{ln(r)} $$ Then determine the values of r (with r>0) for which the series
$$ \sum_1^\infty (\big(r\big)^{ln(n)})$$ converges.
r must be in what interval?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** To show the first thing you are asked to do, find the natural logarithm  of each of the given expressions.

For the second problem, find equivalently the $r$ for which
$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^{-\ln r}}$$
converges. Put in this way, the problem  should feel familiar.

Comment: I get the interval (0,1) but that's not the answer.

Comment: We get convergence if $\ln r\lt -1$, that is, if $0\lt r\lt e^{-1}$.